# For any two coprimes $p,q$ and any natural $n \geq (p-1)(q-1)$, show that $\exists l,m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n = lp + mq$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The Bezout's identity gives the result that there exist integral $l,m$ such that $lp + mq = 1$, as $p,q$ are coprime. But there is no guarantee for positive integral nature of $l,m$ (in fact, to the contrary, one of them is definitely negative).

Had there not been the restriction for positive integral coefficients, the proof would be trivial.

The least number that is expressible in the given form is $p + q$. I am guessing that there will be some use of strong induction. Also I figure that the $n \geq (p-1)(q-1)$ condition is some kind of tip-off, but exactly how ? Please help me approach this better.

Comment: I believe this is the Chicken McNugget theorem.

Comment: i.e. Frobenius coin problem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem

Comment: There is a proof using Bezout's lemma, but there is a better proof that also allows you to determine the exact number of non-solutions. Try drawing a table of the non-negative integers.